# What should the cors origin be for localhost?

Tags: nodes

```
Blocked connection to WebSockets server from untrusted origin: Some("file://")
```

I can't figure out what I should use as an argument for `rpc-cors` to make this websocket connection. I've tried `ws://localhost`, `localhost`, `file://`, none of it seems to work. I am using the Polkadot-Js-AppImage.

Comment: Could you please add more context to your question? What you need is probably `all`.

Comment: @SachaLansky Yes `all` does fix it, but I am trying to see more examples. For example, I have my node behind an Nginx proxy, and so I access it via <IP>:443. How would I specify this for the `rpc-cors` rule?

Comment: Better to disable it and config cors from the nginx side

Comment: @Purple_Turtle did you ever get an answer to this question? if so, can you answer your post below

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi nope. I just do it with rpc-cors all. I do not recall getting it to work with local host or a specific origin only.

Comment: Write that as an answer? Or are you still looking for a config more specific?